# How advanced was the Amiga Walker prototype?

Tags: amiga, commodore

The Amiga Walker was a prototype Amiga computer that never made it to market. [Wikipedia has some info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga_Walker) including a photo of a motherboard.

How advanced was the prototype? Could it boot and run Amiga software, for example? Are the custom chips existing versions from older Amigas, or new revisions that would necessarily be engineering samples? Were any parts missing or non-functional?

I'm asking how close it is to being a completed product that could have been put into production, or even manufactured today were the CAD files made available.

Some additional information found [here](http://obligement.free.fr/articles/walker.php), note that the prototype apparently had performance below that of a basic A1200 due to some issues with it.

Answer (score 5):

> How advanced was the prototype?

At that time, Intel was already selling Pentium 166 (not MMX; MMX models appeared one year later), so ... not very advanced in terms of performance with its Motorola 68030.

If you mean completeness of this prototype, here is [a review](http://www.blachford.info/computer/walker/walker.html) that says that:

> #### Does it work?
>
> Sort of. When powered up it seems to go into a boot
> cycle which it cannot complete and either stops or just keeps
> rebooting. It can be made to get beyond this stage complete with a
> partial Workbench load, but it halts on the error "Not a DOS disk in
> SDH0". Eventually, with patience, it can eventually be made to boot.
>
> This Walker was seen working in late 2002 at the Aachen Amiga show
> after the "Coyte Flux" brothers managed to get it to work.

So yep, it was able to work; not as well as you'd hope when buying a new PC in the store, but able :-)

One more link with [screenshots](http://www.blachford.info/computer/walker/walker_working.html).

Comment: Yes I mean how complete was the prototype.

Comment: I find it odd that the glamor pix used beige CD and floppy in a rather different case.

Answer (score 3):

You may just want to read the Wiki article you linked, as right [the very first reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga_Walker#cite_note-1) (*1) it links to [Nicholas Blachford's page](http://www.blachford.info/computer/walker/walker.html) about his Walker prototype (the vacuumer), including information about it working including this screen shot (taken from that page):

[image: Amiga Walker Workbench]

The Site also includes two more pages ([Walker Working](http://www.blachford.info/computer/walker/walker_working.html) and [Walker Working More](http://www.blachford.info/computer/walker/walker_working_more.html)) with images of running application and a description that it boots fine any classic system from Floppy.

---

*1 - Don't miss to ckeck the other references - that's why they are included anyway.

Comment: Thanks, obviously I read it, but what I'm asking is how close that is to something that is to a usable computer. I'll expand the question.

Comment: @user If booting with a standard Kickstart floppy into Workbench followed by running various application (as shown)  isn't 'working', then what are you looking for? It seams as if the answer you want is nothing RC.SE can give - better contact one of the owner of these boards(about a dozend or so is known) and have him do whatever test you imagine.

Comment: Does the sound work? Is this a standard AGA chipset or are there improvements which were tested and in final form? It's got an '030 CPU and fast RAM, were all those fully functional and debugged?